# Best way to split a Stripe charge across two bank accounts?

Tags: stripe-payments

So when I run a charge, I'd like to be able to have 15% go to a secondary bank account of mine. What's the preferred way to do this now?

I found a great article on exactly this, using recipients and transfers (https://unicornfree.com/2013/using-stripe-to-divvy-up-revenue), but that's been deprecated and replaced with Managed Accounts. But those docs don't offer a clear way to do what I need.

Anyone seen a working example out there?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to setup a "marketplace" type scenario, in which you would use the Stripe Connect platform and have the application_fee parameter in your request which to collect your 15%.

In that scenario, you create a charge request for $100 from customer A, you can specify an application_fee of 1500 (stripe requires the value in cents) in the API call. Documentation on this can be found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees#fees-on-charges).

The result is that the $85 goes to your recipient, and $15 goes into your personal stripe account, and can be transferred to the bank account of your choosing. On hidden "gotcha" to this is that the stripe processing fee will be taken out of your application fee that you charge, so you won't be getting a true 15% from the transaction.

Note, you will need to have a connected or managed account registered through your connect account in order to properly setup the transaction. A general overview on the pros/cons of connected vs managed can be found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connecting-to-accounts).

Comment: Not sure I follow you here. The $85 should come to me, and the $15 should come to me also, but to a second bank account.

Comment: In that case, you'd create a connected/managed account with one of your "primary" bank account on it and direct the charge to go there. You would still use the application_fee parameter so that your "secondary" bank account can receive the smaller portion of funds.

Comment: One other potential option then would be to use the Transfer API to setup a transfer of your 15% funds from your stripe account balance to your secondary bank account. You would most likely need to make sure that "auto transfers" from you stripe account to your primary bank account are disabled, and then setup some kind of web hook to process all incoming payments. Transfer API is found here: https://stripe.com/docs/api#transfers

Note: Doing this will incur a "double transaction" fee. One when your receive funds, and one when you send the second transfer to your other account.